# how to use a project into another

Tags: android

I have a project that I want to use into a different one, I tried to do it as library and as a jar file but it always forces to close it.
I think it´s posible to do it and use all the classes from the package but I don´t know how to do it.
Thanks in advance

---

I added everything but I don´t know how to call the methods in the library
I don´t know how to instantiate a class from the jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the way I created the library, via following this tuto step by step it works fine http://es.slideshare.net/ajdgeniz/como-hacer-un-archivo-jar-en-eclipse then to do the calls there is to import the classes from the library and instantiate them as if they were from the same project, Android recognise the new imported classes

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Making the project a library and exporting it into a jar file only works if you add everything under the `/res` folder of that project to your other project in which you use the jar file. This is because resourced are *not* bundled with the jar, and you'll get errors whenever your library project makes a `R.*.*` reference.

Comment: Thank you Raghav, I´ll try that, what I did was to create another package and put it there but I´ll do what you say in the future